# Chance $r$ people between A and B in circle with $n$ people is independent of $r$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There is the following problem from my probability book.

> If $n$ men, among whom are A and B, stand in a ring, show that the chance that there will be exactly $r$ men between them is independent of $r$.

However, I don't think it's exactly right. When $n$ is odd then the answer is ${\cfrac2{n - 1}}$. Fix A and let it be $1$, if $n = 7$ then we have $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$, $7$ in a circle. For each $k$ ($2 \le k \le 7$) we fix to be B, there's a ${\cfrac{(n - 2)!}{(n-1)!}} = {\cfrac1{n - 1}}$ chance there will be exactly $r = k - 2$ men between them. But wait, there's also the chance there will be exactly $n - r - 2$ men between them on the other side, so we have to multiply by $2$, so we get ${\cfrac2{n - 1}}$. You can check that this works for $n$ odd.

However, for $n$ even, consider $1$, $2$, $3$, $\ldots$, $9$, $10$, where A is set to $1$ and B is set to $6$. Then there's only a ${\cfrac1{n - 1}}$ chance for $r = {\cfrac n2} - 1$ since I can't find another "pair" other than the one $(4, 4)$ in between on both sides.

How do I square this conundrum with what the problem is asking for?

Comment: +1 to your analysis, which I agree with.  Another case of brevity is the soul of poorly worded math problems.  Your analysis has correctly identified *the* flaw in the original assertion.